# Get value from nested json - Bash

Tags: json, key, jq

I had a look around but I cannot find anything that helped, here my problem, I have a bash script that make a curl query and get a json, that look like that:

```
{
  "user1": {
    "email": "email1@email.cccc",
    "shell": "/usr/local/bin/bash",
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "userId": "user1",
    "homeDir": "/home/user1",
    "unixUid": 123456,
    "accesses": [
      "computer1"
    ],
    "personId": 1234,
    "isPrimary": true,
    "projectGroupIds": [
      "bigproj"
    ],
    "primaryProjectGroupId": "bigproj"
  },
  "user2": {
    "email": "email2@email.cccc",
    "shell": "/usr/local/bin/bash",
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "userId": "user2",
    "homeDir": "/home/user2",
    "unixUid": 9876564,
    "accesses": [
      "computer1"
    ],
    "personId": 5678,
    "isPrimary": true,
    "projectGroupIds": [
      "smallporj"
    ],
    "primaryProjectGroupId": "smallproj"
...
```

What I need to do is to create a list, that contains:

```
UserId: user1  email: email1@email.cccc
UserId: user2  email: email2@email.cccc
UserId: user3  email: email3@email.cccc
...
```

My problem is that the username key, is basically always changing and it doesn't have a fix key name.
The top key types are:

```
jq -c 'to_entries[] | [.key, (.value|type)]'
["meta","object"]
["body","object"]
```

So what should be the best approach to create a list that I'll need to compare with another one?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Would this work for you?

```
jq -c 'to_entries[] | "UserId: " + .key + "  email: " + .value.email '
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach:

```
  keys_unsorted[] as $key
  | "UserId: \($key)  email: \(.[$key].email)"
```